# How do I get particles to follow an animated path or armature?

Tags: armature, particles, bezier-curves, force-fields

I'm doing this wormhole tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2WTH016rfk and I'm trying to get particles to also follow through the animated tunnel. Emitting from the far end and coming toward the camera. The problem is that the wormhole is wiggling around and the particles don't follow the animated path.

I was able to add a bezier curve and control it with the armature and use it as a curve guide force field. I controlled the position of the emitter with the armature as well.  particles don't stay on the curve when it wiggles around. And the curve doesn't follow the armature very well either.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for posting your question so clearly.

Time to get serious with particles: Select your tunnel, enter EDIT mode, switch to FACE selection filter, select all faces. Go to the MESH menu>NORMALS>Flip normals. Now all your normals should be pointing INSIDE your tunnel.

2) Switch back to OBJECT mode, now apply a SOLIDIFY MODIFIER, and make it thick enough so that when you deform your object it will deform correctly (like a real tunnel thickness)

3) Go to the dynamics tab and click COLLISION. Set friction to something like 0.2, 0.5

4) Now when you playback your animation, your (already working curve guide force) should be working and particles will not be able to scape the tunnel. Furthermore the expected behavior of the particles will react to the deformation of the tunnel.

Thank you for your consideration to vote this as the answer.

BFCT_Schiller

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually don't want the particles to interact with the tunnel at all. I just want them following the path inside the tunnel (the path is selected and orange in the photo). The problem is that the path moves around, but the particles don't follow that movement.